# PHP : create dynamic zip file from directory and dowload it from href link

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I create zip file from directory like this :

```
<?php // On instancie la classe.
        $zip = new ZipArchive();

        if($zip->open($cheminAlbum.'.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE) == TRUE)
        {

         $fichiers = scandir($cheminAlbum.'/');
        // On enlève . et .. qui représentent le dossier courant et le dossier parent.
         unset($fichiers[0], $fichiers[1]);

        foreach($fichiers as $f) {
                if(!$zip->addFile($cheminAlbum.'/'.$f, $f)) {
                    echo 'Impossible d&#039;ajouter &quot;'.$f.'&quot;.<br/>';
                } else {
                    echo 'Fichier ajouter &quot; : '.$f.'&quot;.<br/>';
                }
         }

        $zip->close();

        } else {
            echo 'Erreur, impossible de créer l&#039;archive.';
    }

 ?>
```

I add link for download it like this :

```
<a href="<?php echo $cheminAlbum.'.zip';?>"> Download Album </a>
```

When i access to directory, i dont found the zip file after call php page
And when i click to the link, the file doesnt exist

The file is add correctly to the zip when i debug (add echo)

what i forgot in y code ?

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is with the file name. your code is creating a foldername/.zip file instead of foldername/album1.zip check the below code add a dynamic filename in url and when opending

when creating and providing access to files you need to consider two things. when creating file you need to use File System path and when you are providing link you need to provide url of the file

```
<?php // On instancie la classe.
        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        $filename = "somealbumName";
        if($zip->open($cheminAlbum.'/'.$filename.'.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE) == TRUE)
        {

         $fichiers = scandir($cheminAlbum.'/');
        // On enlève . et .. qui représentent le dossier courant et le dossier parent.
         unset($fichiers[0], $fichiers[1]);

        foreach($fichiers as $f) {
                if(!$zip->addFile($cheminAlbum.'/'.$f, $f)) {
                    echo 'Impossible d&#039;ajouter &quot;'.$f.'&quot;.<br/>';
                } else {
                    echo 'Fichier ajouter &quot; : '.$f.'&quot;.<br/>';
                }
         }

        $zip->close();

        } else {
            echo 'Erreur, impossible de créer l&#039;archive.';
    }

 ?>
 <a href="<?php echo $cheminAlbum.'/'.$filename.'.zip';?>"> Download Album </a>
```

Comment: I try it also, i've the same probleme

Comment: The requested URL /website/images/album1/somealbumName.zip was not found on this server.

Comment: The website is subdirectory in wamp (wamp/www/website)

Comment: if you are using windows use \\ when creating zip file instead of / and check if the file is created or not in the destination folder. When creating and providing access to files you need to consider two things. when creating file you need to use File System path and when you are providing link you need to provide url of the file

Comment: I've change with \\, the zip file wasn't created in directory

Comment: this script working fine my files are located in c:\php\test and it is my document root folder so i can download any thing that is created in it example c:\php\test\album.zip can be downloaded using localhost/album.zip refer to the script http://pastebin.com/yS4jEADd

Comment: I think it's my wamp who dont create, because i try to use this code and zip file was not created. The version of my php in wamp is : 5.5.12

Answer (score 0):

Unless it's defined in another file you haven't shown, $cheminAlbum would have no value. So, your anchor leads nowhere.
Have you tried adding debug statements such as printing values of variables with print_r()? Are you sure you have your variables defined and the files they are defined in included if not in the file you are accessing them from?

Comment: Yes i print the value of $cheminAlbum, itsn't empty, for example the value = images/album1/album1.zip

Comment: @user3817737 If the value = images/album1/album1.zip, you open a .zip named album1.zip.zip.

Comment: the zip is include not 'zip.zip'

Comment: "if($zip->open($cheminAlbum.'.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE) == TRUE)" – If $cheminAlbum is what you said it is, you would create a .zip.zip file. Can you give me an actual value of $cheminAlbum?

Comment: The value of cheminAlbum is : images/album1

Comment: the main problem is with the file name. Use some other file name you are giving the folder name to open a file in $zip->open($cheminAlbum.'/'.$filename.'.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE) == TRUE)

Comment: same problem: i've put static value in variable $filename as 'file1'

Comment: Try looking at the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.open.php) for ZipArchive. Check for the returned values on open() and close() and print them, either with echo or print_r.

Answer (score 0):

I used this function, the zip is created well in the folder. I intend that after downloading, the zip is deleted from the server

```
<?php // On instancie la classe.
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $filename = "$nom_ref";
    $cheminAlbum = "../../../../Images-Produits/2018/$nom_ref";
    if($zip->open($cheminAlbum.'/'.$filename.'.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE) == TRUE)
    {

     $fichiers = scandir($cheminAlbum.'/');
    // On enlève . et .. qui représentent le dossier courant et le dossier parent.
     unset($fichiers[0], $fichiers[1]);

    foreach($fichiers as $f) {
            if(!$zip->addFile($cheminAlbum.'/'.$f, $f)) {
                //echo 'Impossible d&#039;ajouter &quot;'.$f.'&quot;.<br/>';
            } else {
                //echo 'Fichier ajouter &quot; : '.$f.'&quot;.<br/>';
            }
     }

    $zip->close();

    } else {
        //echo 'Erreur, impossible de créer l&#039;archive.';
        }

     ?>

    <a href="<?php echo $cheminAlbum.'/'.$filename.'.zip';?>" action="action" class="btn btn-dropbox" title="Télécharger <?php echo $nom_ref; ?>.zip" style="float: left;">
    <i class="fa fa-download"></i>&nbsp; TÉLÉCHARGER .ZIP</a>
```